# Azure Storage Calculated MD5 does not match existing property

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-storage

I'm trying to pass an Azure Storage blob through an ashx. On the  **blockBlob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream)** it's throwing the following Exception: `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: Calculated MD5 does not match existing property`

I know it's finding the correct blob. If I put in a container and path that don't exist then it gives me a 404 exception instead.

I've Googled for hints on what might be causing this error but nothing useful is coming up. Does anyone have any thoughts on what might be causing this? I've rewritten this code a couple different ways over the last couple days but it always dies on DownloadToStream.

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
    // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
    Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

    // Create the blob client.
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("gmt");

    // Retrieve reference to blob named "articles/142/222.jpg".
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("articles/142/222.jpg");

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
        blockBlob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
        byte[] photoByte = ReadFully(memoryStream);
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(photoByte, 0, photoByte.Length);
    }
}

public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input) {
    input.Position = 0;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
        input.CopyTo(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to recreate the problem you're facing. This happens if the `Content MD5` property of the blob is somehow corrupted. I had a blob with some content MD5 (which was correct). I then programmatically changed the MD5 to some other value (which is incorrect). Now when I call DownloadToStream() method on the blob, I get exact same error.

You can bypass this check by setting `DisableContentMD5Validation` to `true` in `BlobRequestOptions` as shown in the code below:

```
            BlobRequestOptions options = new BlobRequestOptions()
            {
                DisableContentMD5Validation = true,
            };
            blockBlob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream, null, options);
```

Give it a try and it should work.

On a side note, you may want to modify your `ReadFully` method as well. You would need to move the `input` stream pointer to the beginning.

```
    public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
    {
        input.Position = 0;//Positioning it to the top of stream.
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            input.CopyTo(ms);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out tonight. I uploaded 13 gigs of images using the FTP to Azure Blob Storage Bridge. Every file I tried gives me this error message. I wonder if this is what corrupted all of the files.

Comment: that made the exception go away thanks. the ashx is still just returning 0 bytes though. booooooo...

Comment: Just check the position of `ms` in `ReadFully()` function of yours. Make sure it is also at 0.

Comment: ah, i found it. there's another mistake in my code. I need to ReadFully(memoryStream) and not stream. That's just some empty MemoryStream object. It works now! Thank you so much for your help and quick responses. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem on my local DEV environment. And it seems that db of `AzureStorageEmulator` got corrupted.

The solution (for local env!):

- drop the emulator's db (e.g. `AzureStorageEmulatorDb57`)
- run `AzureStorageEmulator.exe init -sqlinstance .` (you may need to customize the instance name)
- run `AzureStorageEmulator.exe start`
- restart the application, so it gets a new handler to the emulator

Comment: from where to drop emulators db. Not getting the steps. Please explain in more detail

Comment: @Preeti - the emulator create a database on your local SQL Server instance. During first initialisation you had to specify the SQL instance, so the emulator can store its data these. In the steps above the dot "." means "default local sql server instance".

Comment: Stopping everything and dropping the emulator DB and then relaunching the application is all I needed to do. It auto starts the emulator and automatically recreated the emulatorDb and VOILA, no more errors! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I used `AzureStorageEmulator.exe init -forcecreate`. Described in this [link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=392235). MD5 error message is now gone.